# AttributeError: log10 in python

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm creating a customized block in the GNU Radio framework using python that takes in a number of input items and once that number of input items surpasses a certain number, 1024 of the input items are taken and stored into an array, and then those items are converted to dB and lastly compared to a threshold value, 5 in this case. If any of the values are greater than the threshold value, a message is printed indicating a signal is present, and if none of the values are greater than 5, this is indicated with a message stating "No signal is present". The code is shown below.

```
def general_work(self, input_items, output_items):
    in0 = input_items[0]
    self.seen+=in0.shape[0]
    print "Number of input items:", self.seen
    if self.seen>self.num_values:   
        in1= islice(in0, 1024)    #1024 values are taken from the variable in0 and stored in in1
        c = np.log10(in1)         #converts 1024 values stored in in1 to dB and stores them in c
        if c.all() > 5.0:         #checks if any of the values stored in c are greater than c

           print "A signal is present"
             #print "The values greater than the threshold are", a>5
        else:
           print "No signal is present"       

        self.seen = 0
    self.consume_each(in0.shape[0]) #consume everything you've account for
                                # tell system to move on to next samples

    return 0        ##return 0 samples generated
                    ## as the block doesn't have an output stream
```

When I run the flow graph which uses this block I get the following error.

> c = np.log10(in1)         #converts 1024 values stored in in1 to dB and stores them in c
>
> AttributeError: log10
>   thread[thread-per-block[8]: ]: caught unrecognized exception

I'm assuming this issue has to do with the values being too big.

Comment: `in1` is an `islice` instance (which is an iterable over the first 1024 elements in `in0`).  What does it mean to call `float` on it?

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your question but I used "float(in1)" because I thought the error I was getting might be an indication that the values in in1 aren't floats so I was trying to convert those values, which might not be necessary

Comment: @TellrellWhite you're trying to mask another error with wrong Python. So, remove the float() and show us the error you're getting.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited my original message and it results in the error shown above

Comment: well, indeed, `math.log10()` can't deal with iterables. Either use `numpy.log10` or do something pythonic like `[math.log10(num) for num in in1]`.

Comment: Using np.log10 results in the AttributeError listed above. I'm going to try the other approach mentioned by Marcus

Comment: As a followup, I've looked more into this error. It has nothing to do with the values being too big. It means that the np object doesn't have a log10 attribute or functionality and I'm not quite clear on why that is. Is this a environmental issue within the framework or something else?